# OANDA / TRADING

Tags: trading

I am trying to deploy my algo on OANDA and I keep getting tis error.

Could anyone help please?

Thanks  a lot in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the authentication params were not correct. Try this with [oanda's v20 wrapper](https://github.com/oanda/v20-python)

```
import v20
token = 'YOUR API TOKEN'
account_id = 'YOUR ACCOUNT ID'

# using oanda's v20 API wrapper
ctxs=v20.Context(hostname='stream-fxpractice.oanda.com', token=token)
ctxs.set_header(key='Authorization', value=token)

# send the request to the stream endpoint
response=ctxs.pricing.stream(account_id, instruments='EUR_USD,GBP_USD')

# process the incoming stream tick by tick
for typ, data in response.parts():
   if typ == "pricing.ClientPrice":
       msg="{} ({}) {}/{}".format(
          data.instrument, 
          data.time,
          data.bids[0].price,
          data.asks[0].price)
       print(msg)
       break
```